# How do i change iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk, xcode4.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i change my iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14240013/how-can-i-change-my-ios-sdk)

I have xCode 4.3.3 and iOs SDK 5.1
I need to be iOS SDK 4.3. How can i change my sdk? may be you have links on same problem? Thanx

Comment: Isn't this a duplication question of what you posted yesterday?

Answer (score 2):

In the project settings there are two fields called Base SDK and Deployment Target. Your Base SDK should be latest available (currently 6.0) and your Deployment Target can be the desired version (4.3).

Comment: You don't need to change the base sdk, just the deployment target. You do, however, need to be aware of which functions/classes you're using that are supported for certain iOS versions.

Comment: it requires just only SDK 4.3 Any changes at Deployment Target doesn't help.I don't need to compile my app on simulator sdk 4.3. I total i need to have iOS SDK 4.3 with my xCode

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't help"? I don't really understand the problem right now.

Comment: @AttilaH Yes this question is unclear in general. It's a duplicate of this which has a little more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14240013/how-can-i-change-my-ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preference  And Check Whether The iOS SDK 4.3 is installed or Not or else you can download and install.

```
Xcode-> Preferences-> Downloads
```

Here you can see the List of available Downloads. then click on install.

After Download installation finish Just Restart X-code.

Then Select your deployment target.

```
Project --> info-->iOS Deployment target 

Targets-->Summary-->Deployment target
```

Select the desired SDK.